# Expand variable in function definition in zsh

Tags: zsh, function

I want to generate a set of functions in my shell in a `for` loop, but I can't see how to access a variable inside the function body of the function I'm creating.

In essence, I would like the following

```
for f in foo ; do $f() { echo $f } ; done
```

to generate a function `foo() { echo foo }`, but instead I get `foo() { echo $f }`.

I've read the section on parameter expansion flags in the zsh manual, but whatever I write after `$f()` seems to be put verbatim into the generated function's body, so I had no luck.

Maybe this is the wrong way to do this? If not I want to know how I can expand `$f` inside the function when it's generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's typically a case where you need `eval`.

```
$ for f (foo) eval "\$f() echo ${(qq)f}"
$ which foo
foo () {
    echo 'foo'
}
```